# swift share information between two classes

Tags: swift, class, inheritance

I have a tabbed view app that I am working on right now I am wondering if there's any way I can share the information from my FirstViewController.swift to my SecondViewController.swift? Since I know swift doesnt support multiple class inheritance, is there a way that I can use the variables and informations I have on my FirstViewController in my SecondViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a model outside the context of both your view controllers to store data, and then a way to populate those view controllers with that data and provide a reference to the model to make changes from the view controllers.  You could this by creating a new model object that conforms to `UITabBarColtronnerDelegate`, which will allow you access to a view controller after it is selected.  Keep things decoupled by abstracting these relationships into protocols, which then allows your implementations to vary independently as your app scales up.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let applicationModel = ApplicationModel()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        if let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            tabBarController.delegate = applicationModel
        }
        return true
    }
}

protocol TabbedViewControllerDelegate {
    var message: String { set get }
}

class ApplicationModel: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate, TabbedViewControllerDelegate {

    var message = "Hello World!"

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        if var tabbedViewController = viewController as? TabbedViewController {
            tabbedViewController.message = message
            tabBarController.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

protocol TabbedViewController {
    var message: String { set get }
    var delegate: TabbedViewControllerDelegate? { get set }
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, TabbedViewController {

    var delegate: TabbedViewControllerDelegate?

    var message: String = "" {
        didSet {
            println( "FirstViewController populated with message: \(message)" )
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed( sender: AnyObject? ) {
        self.delegate?.message = "Updated message from FirstViewController"
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, TabbedViewController {

    var delegate: TabbedViewControllerDelegate?

    var message: String = "" {
        didSet {
            println( "SecondViewController populated with message: \(message)" )
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed( sender: AnyObject? ) {
        self.delegate?.message = "Updated message from SecondViewController"
    }
}
```